# How to remove an element(s) from several arrays and append again?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

I have a function with several arrays of `CGPoint`s and array of arrays. I have been 'manually' removing points from each of the arrays and appending them back one by one. This is certainly a tedious and inefficient approach. I am looking for a more efficient way to handle removing and appending points to the arrays. Here's my code:

```
func setSpritePositions ()   {
   groupA1 = [p1, p4, p6, p8]
   groupA2 = [p1, p3, p2, p5]

   groupB1 = [p1, p7, p2, p6]
   groupB2 = [p9, p4, p3, p2]
   groupB2 = [p2, p4, p5, p8]

   groupC1 = [p1, p7, p2, p7]
   groupC2 = [p9, p4, p3, p2]
   groupC3 = [p4, p5, p6, p7]
   groupC4 = [p5, p1, p3, p4]

   groupA = [groupA1, groupA2]
   groupB = [groupB1, groupB2, groupB3]
   groupC = [groupC1, groupC2, groupC3, groupC4]

   groups = [groupA, groupB, groupC]

}
```

For example, how would I remove points `p1`, `p3` and `p7` from the arrays that contain them and take note of the arrays and append the positions back. How would I achieve that? As I said, I've been doing it one by one, which is too cumbersome.

**UPDATE**

I am using the various groups of positions to limit movement of a sprite in my game. At times I would want to remove certain positions and be able to tell which arrays to append them back to later.

Comment: Iterate `groups`. For each array, iterate its arrays. And for each of those arrays, see if it contains the point. If so, delete and then append it.

Comment: @rmaddy Are you referring to accessing all other arrays through `groups`? I am using all the other arrays so changes in `groups` alone wouldn't be effected in the other since swift arrays are value types. I was considering using `NSArray`s but it would be very, very difficult to manipulate them to get certain results.

Comment: "and append the positions back" Do you really mean append here (as in, put at the end of the array), or do you really mean "sometimes p1 is active, and sometimes it is not." I'm assuming the latter, and that if p1 is inactive for one group, it is inactive for all groups.

Comment: @RobNapier  Yes, if a point say,  `p1` is inactive for one group is inactive for all. In effect making points active or inactive would achieve the same result as removing and appending. Though it seems that the approach of making points active and inactive could be a better solution.

Comment: @RobNapier Could you please take a look at the following question for me. I would really appreciate any assistance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120076/how-can-i-remove-a-certain-cgpoint-from-a-dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is better types. First, if you want points to have shared state, then you want a reference type, not a value type. You should lift your points into a reference Location:

```
final class Location {
    let point: CGPoint
    var isActive: Bool = true
    init(_ point: CGPoint) { self.point = point }
}
```

Now you can turn locations on and off.

Here's an example of how you could use that with better types. There are many ways to design this; this is just one. You can then group locations into segments:

```
struct LocationSegment {
    let locations: [Location]
    var activePoints: [CGPoint] { 
        return locations.filter{ $0.isActive }.map{ $0.point }.uniqueValues()
    }
}
```

This makes it easy to get the list of activePoints. This assumes an extension like:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    // Warning: This is O(n^2). You can't do better than that without making CGPoint Hashable
    // (which is easy, but left as a separate problem.)
    func uniqueValues() -> [Element] {
        var result: [Element] = []
        for element in self {
            if !result.contains(element) {
                result.append(element)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Now that we have segments, we can put them in groups:

```
struct LocationGroup {
    let segments: [LocationSegment]
    var activePoints: [CGPoint] { return segments.flatMap { $0.activePoints }.uniqueValues() }
}
```

And if we had an array of groups:

```
let groups = [groupA, groupB, groupC]
```

We could get all the active points:

```
groups.flatMap { $0.activePoints }
```

Again, this is just one approach. You might want `groups` to be a stronger type than `[LocationGroup]`, or you may want to redesign `LocationGroup` to be a recursive enum so you could build this entirely with value types (though I think this particular problem cries out for a reference type at the bottom). The point is to build types that say what you mean rather than trying to force Arrays to be everything you want.

Comment: Wow! this didn't only solve this problem but it solved half a dozen other problems I had. Thanks a lot, really grateful.