# How can I remove a certain CGPoint from a dictionaries

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary, filter, swift3

I have seen a number of posts on looping through a dictionary but they are a different and simpler than what I want to achieve here, in my opinion. I have the following arrays:

```
pt1.array = [0:[pt2.point], 
             1:[pt8.point, pt12.point, pt4.point],  
             2:[pt20.point, pt14.point, pt3.point], 
             3:[pt7.point, pt8.point, pt9.point]]
pt2.array = [0:[pt5.point], 
             1:[pt8.point, pt11.point, pt1.point], 
             2:[pt10.point, pt9.point, pt3.point], 
             3:[pt6.point, pt1.point, pt4.point]]
pt3.array = [0:[pt13.point], 
             1:[pt1.point, pt15.point, pt7.point], 
             2:[pt19.point, pt14.point, pt2.point], 
             3:[pt10.point, pt11.point, pt12.point]]
pt4.array = [0:[pt8.point], 
             1:[pt9.point, pt11.point, pt13.point],
             2:[pt14.point, pt15.point, pt6.point], 
             3:[pt3.point, pt2.point, pt1.point]]
pt5.array = [0:[pt18.point], 
             1:[pt8.point, pt6.point, pt1.point], 
             2:[pt3.point, pt17.point, pt4.point], 
             3:[pt16.point, pt15.point, pt14.point]]

allPoints = [pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5]
```

How can I iterate to remove `pt3.point` which is a CGPoint from all the `Int`-`[CGPoint]` dictionaries in the `allPoints` array?

I tried the following:

```
for pt in allPoints {
    for ptArrIndex in pt.arrays    {

        for (key, value) in ptArrIndex   {
            //remove point from dict here
        }
    }
}
```

but I got the error:

```
Type '(key: Int, value:[CGPoint])' (aka'(key: Int, value: Array<CGPoint>)') does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'
```

at the line:

```
for (key, value) in ptArrIndex   {
```

**EDIT**

The struct that creates each of the points is below:

```
struct Point {
    var point: CGPoint
    var arrays: [Int: [CGPoint]]
}
```

**UPDATED QUESTION**

Based on Rob Napier’s suggestion I’ve updated the question:

I have a struct below:

```
struct Location {
    var point: CGPoint
    var changedLoc: [Int: [CGPoint]]
}
```

where `point` represents a `CGPoint` for `Location` and `changedLoc` represents all the possible groups of CGPoints `Location` can change to. I calculate this randomly.

I have the following Locations

```
var location1 = Location(point: initialBallPosition, changedLoc: [0: [CGPoint(x: 421.0, y: 43.0), CGPoint(x: 202.0, y: 69.0)], 1: [CGPoint(x: 121.0, y: 198.0)]])
var location2 = Location(point: initialBallPosition, changedLoc: [0: [CGPoint(x: 421.0, y: 43.0), CGPoint(x: 123.0, y: 254.0)], 1: [CGPoint(x: 90.0, y: 104.0)]])

var allLocations = [location1, location2]
```

From `allLocations` how can I remove the point `CGPoint(x: 421.0, y: 43.0)` which is in both `location1` and `location2` `changedLoc`?

Comment: The dictionaries don't look like `[Int : CGPoint]`, but `[Int : [CGPoint]]`.

Comment: @IvensDenner I updated the question with what I've tried out

Comment: can someone help me out :)

Comment: You've named to many things "point" here, and I think it's confusing both you and readers. `allPoints` isn't an `[[Int: [CGPoint]]`, its `[Point]`. I suggest going back to a simpler example (that doesn't require 20 `pt` variables). Provide the full input and the full desired output, and just leave the `remove` piece. This doesn't look like a difficult problem; it's difficult because the code above is contradictory and ambiguous. For example, is it `.array` or `.arrays`? What is `.point`? If `.point` matches `pt3.point`, should the whole element be removed? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @RobNapier thank you for the suggestion. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func locationsRemoving(changedLoc removePoint: CGPoint, from locations: [Location]) -> [Location] {
    return locations.map { location in
        var changedLoc: [Int: [CGPoint]] = [:]
        for (key, values) in location.changedLoc {
            changedLoc[key] = values.filter{ $0 != removePoint }
        }
        return Location(point: location.point, changedLoc: changedLoc)
    }
}

let removePoint = CGPoint(x: 421.0, y: 43.0)
print(allLocations)
print(locationsRemoving(changedLoc: removePoint, from: allLocations))
```

Comment: Thanks. What happens in the case that there is a `removePoints` array of `CGPoints` to be removed?

Comment: Then check `removePoints.contains($0)` rather than `!=`. (Make sure you understand what each line of this code does; it's intended to be straightforward; if you haven't any confusion over exactly how it works, keep studying and asking questions until you know how to maintain it; don't just copy it.)

Answer (score 0):

The confusing thing you have is that the property named `array` in the `ptN` instances is actually a `Dictionary<Int, [CGPoint]>`

So, for the structure you currently have, you'll need to amend your code to match:

```
for pt in allPoints {
    for (key, ptArray) in pt.array    {
        for elem in ptArray   {
            //remove point from dict here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying to find a way to remove the the point. In place of the comment I put                         `if elem  ==  pt3.point  {
                            ptArray.remove(at: ptArray.index(of: elem))
                        }` but this gives me the error `Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'ptArray' is a  'let' constant` which I understand. Just that I am not too sure how I'll remove the point from `ptArray`

Comment: Instead of iterating `ptArray`, you could try: `pt.array = ptArray.filter { $0 != pt3.point }`. That would require `array` to be declared as `var`.

Comment: I'm wondering, though, if this is the right path. Do you want to share some of the larger picture of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: The above code in your comment practically comes to a similar issue. The error `cannot assign to property: 'pt' is a 'let' constant`. Basically I have a struct with two properties. An `array` of [int: [CGPoint]] property and a `point` property. The idea here is the array represents a number of points that can be reached from one point, so when one point is reached I randomly select a new point to be used and so on. That part of the code is okay. Now I want to remove a particular point so it's unreachable. Thats what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Why is the value of `point` in `array`? Can we filter it out when `array` is generated? Or filter it out later when you want to make use of that `array`?

Comment: I have made a copy of the original `allPoints` because I'll revert back to it. I want to filter `pt3.point` from the copy. Also I used pt1.point.... and so on in my question to make reading easier but I am actually using `CGPoint` values like ` CGPoint(x: 271, y: 181)` in my code for the arrays. I'll need the original `allPoints` later so I can't filter when it is generated. I hope this answers your questions

Comment: @OnlyCodeMatters Are you aware of the difference between reference and value types? For instance, even if you could change `ptArray` (i.e, if it was a `var`), you wouldn't change the actual array of `CGPoint`s, but just a copy of it, since `Array` is a value type. Read more about it and maybe consider changing a little bit your structure, it looks quite confusing to me.

Comment: @IvensDenner I just updated the question with my `Point` struct. I understand your explanation on arrays being value types. How do you suggest change the structure to handle my issue?